# Embed latitude/longitude of several places in an HTML page so that Android GPS apps can use it?

Tags: browser, gps, maps, html, android-intent

I am writing [an HTML page](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Copenhagen/Amager) where the geographical coordinates (longitude+latitude) of several places are listed:

- Amagermuseet (latitude=55.6008968 longitude=12.6360609)
- Flakfortet (latitude=55.7035835 longitude=12.7317048)

How can I somehow embed a link or something, so that Android users can open the geographical location in their favorite Map/GPS app as easily as possible?

If there were a generic way to launch an intent from a web page that would be acceptable as well, but I guess that's not possible. If the solution could work on non-Android devices as well, that would be even better, but for now Android-only is fine.

The [Geotagging microformat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging#Microformat) does not work in my tests on Android 4 with Firefox and the stock browser. The [ICBM method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging#ICBM_method) is not usable because it specifies coordinates for the whole page, can't specify several places in a single page.